# Groovy in jenkins behaviour of list after applying remove()

Tags: groovy, jenkins, behavior

I'm quite a beginner when it comes to working with jenkins+ groovy.

I'm working on a groovy script to identify the current queued jobs and remove any duplicates if they have a specific string in their name.
What I currently have is the following:

```
import hudson.model.*  

q = jenkins.model.Jenkins.getInstance().getQueue()
items = q.getItems()
names = []

for (i=0;i<items.size();i++) {  
  names << items[i].task.getName()
}

names.sort()

println("#################################")
println("names[i] list with the component elements: \n")
for (i=0;i<names.size();i++) {
  println(names[i])
}

for (i=0;i<names.size();i++) {
  if (names[i].contains('Component')) {
    //do nothing
  } else {
    names.remove(i)
  }
}


println("#################################")
println("names[i] list without the component elements: \n")
for (i=0;i<names.size();i++) {
  println(names[i])
}
```

So I get my jenkins queue, I retrieve the name of the job, I sort it and then I remove from the names[] list any name that doesn't contain the string 'Component' in it.

I then try to print out the names[] list to see if all the appropriate names have been removed. Here is the output that I get for my code:

```
#################################
names[i] list with the component elements: 

TEST1_CJ
TEST2_CJ
rm-feat-rm-Consolidation_win64
rm-feat-rm-Vote_win64
acquisition-rm-feat-rm-Component_win64
data-rm-feat-rm-Vote_win64
lumiop-rm-feat-rm-Component_win64
ludesk-rm-feat-rm-Component_win64
lutop-rm-Component_win64
rm-feat-rm-Component_win64
#################################
names[i] list with the component elements: 

TEST2_CJ
rm-feat-rm-Vote_win64
acquisition-rm-feat-rm-Component_win64
lumiop-rm-feat-rm-Component_win64
ludesk-rm-feat-rm-Component_win64
lutop-rm-Component_win64
rm-feat-rm-Component_win64
```

It kind of seems that the names.remove() is working half-arsed. It seems it removed only test1, consolidation and the second vote, but it didnt remove test2 and the other vote.

Could anybody explain to me the behaviour of names.remove() maybe I'm missing something. The groovy documentation doesn't really offer me anything so...

Thanks!!

Comment: if you are not after performance, you might rather use the more functional approach to handling lists in groovy. e.g. `names.each{ println it }` or `names = items*.task*.name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you remove items from the list you are iterating over.  for what you are after, there is `filterAll` in groovy.  apply it on a list and it returns all elements, that return groovy-truth when applied to the closure.  e.g.

```
def namesWithComponent = names.findAll{ it.contains('Component') }
```

Comment: thanks, does exactly what i need it to do :) and it's clean and simple